# FastReport "CheckBox"

Tags: fastreport

I am having a hard time trying to understand how to work with checkboxes in FastReport Editor. I simply try to change the checkbox from "Checked" to "Unchecked", but it seems to ignore my expression. I tried a variety of things to put inside the expression, but it always seem to ignore it and "Checked" is always true. Funny enough, if I change the binding to another database, "Checked" becomes false, no matter the expression.. How can I change the "checked" state using the expression? Maybe I got my spelling wrong or Idk.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

i see the question is a little bit older now, so i don't know how relevant this still is for you.

but from first glance it seems you want your checkbox with the name CheckBox2 to not be checked, right?

in that case you just write down `false` in your expression. To show an empty box you also have to set a border in the border property. Otherwise there will be nothing to see.

if you want it to be checked if some other condition is met you write in your expression `SomeCondition == someValue`

Basically the expression is what you would write inside the brackets after an `if` in c#

if that is true your checkbox will be checked if not it won't.